# How to perform generic lookup in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Suppose I have this collection:

```
{
   "_id":{
      "$oid":"5fc2950883c843a134980620"
   },
   "name":"Legs",
   "url":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yXH-_hMf_Vs&t=527s",
   "tags":[
      {
         "$oid":"5fc82b4969562b1584bed619"
      },
      {
         "$oid":"5fcbe6846674f842d41c6bf1"
      }
   ],
   "exercises":[
      {
         "$oid":"5fc29042d8afdc3aec64e8f1"
      },
      {
         "$oid":"5fce7025371a883f08e51239"
      }
   ],
   "date":{
      "$date":{
         "$numberLong":"1602277200000"
      }
   }
}
```

I want my query to return to the full data, which means that in each time I encounter object id I want to go to that collection and get the whole object. For example when I am in the tags array I want for each tag id to be replaced with the whole object from the tags collection.
How can that be achieved with a mongo query? I don't want to store all the objects in the same collection, i.e. the tags ids for example are foreign keys in this collection and primary keys in the tags collection.
Exactly the same should be applied for each array that contains ids, like exercises in this example.

Comment: You can perform multiple lookup in aggregation to achieve this.

Comment: But the probem is I dont know which collection it will be and I wanted to also try poulate but the problem that I cant know when I want to go down one leve, it depends in each level I see foreign ids

Comment: Why dont you post some data

Comment: I want it to be normalized